# Did the wizarding world interfere with the muggle world?

Tags: harry-potter

Another question that bothers me: when muggles had big problems and wars going on, did the wizarding world interfere?

Did they help or interfere with the muggles in the world war or even in wars earlier than that? Against Napoleon or in the war against the Roman Empire? Couldn't they prevent the wars and battles?

Comment: Why would they want to? Napoleon was rad.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/First_World_War

Comment: It should also be noted that there's no *particular* reason to think Napoleon (for example) even existed in Harry Potter's world.  I mean, [he **probably** did](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LikeRealityUnlessNoted), but there's no explicit evidence of that as far as I'm aware.  (Warning: TV Tropes link.)

Comment: ... the obvious problem would be that wizards would likely be involved on both sides, which would seriously endanger the Statute of Secrecy.  There's something analogous to that discussed in *The Dresden Files*, if I can put my thoughts in order I might try to write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

They did interfere some times. Harry's great grandfather Henry spoke out against the Minister of Magic at the time who had forbade wizards from protecting muggles in the WW1.